# Comparing results of svy_vglm regression models ('survey','svy_VGAM','mitools','mice' in R)

Tags: r, linear-regression, survey, r-mice, vgam

I'm running regression models on multiple imputations of complex survey data set with the R packages 'survey', 'svy_VGAM' and 'mitools'. I use svy_VGAM::svy_vglm() on a svyimputationList (created in 'mitools'), then combine the results with mitools::MIcombine, resulting in a MIresult object. The models differ in terms of model family (cumulative, sratio, acat, bernoulli) and link functions (probit, logit, cloglog), as well as predictor variable(s).

Now I need to compare the models.  None of the packages' documentation discusses how to do this.  Diagnostics in other packages don't accept the pooled svy_vglm output in 'miresult' objects.  For example, when I convert the uncombined svy_vglm models from survey::with to a 'mira' object to pool (with mice::pool()) or assess (with mice::D1() for the Wald test or mice::D3() for likelihood ratio), I get the error "No tidy method for objects of class svy_vglm"

What tools are available to create plots and run diagnostics on the output from survey::with or mitools::MIcombine?  More broadly, can anyone advise on how to one compare regressions of multiply imputed. reweighted complex survey data modeled with this software?

(Please note that I have asked a different question about a different topic regarding this same study. I apologize for the appearance of redundancy.)

Comment: This is pretty broad, especially without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862). It is probably also better suited at [stats.se], since it's about model diagnostics more than debugging the code necessary to build those models